# Excel Error as "You've entered too few arguements"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
=IF(AND(TIME(HOUR(B5), MINUTE(B5), SECOND(B5))>TIMEVALUE("6:30 PM"), D5=1), (TIME(hours(C5), MINUTE(C5), SECOND(C5))-TIMEVALUE("9:30 AM")), (TIME(hours(C5), MINUTE(C5), SECOND(C5))-TIMEVALUE("9:30 AM")+TIMEVALUE("9:00 AM")))
```

Giving error as `You've entered too few argument`

Kindly help.

Comment: You seems to be using `Hours` instead of `Hour`. Is that a `VBA` function?

Answer (score 0):

The only error I could see was you are using `HOURS`, it should be `HOUR`:

```
=IF(AND(TIME(HOUR(B5), MINUTE(B5), SECOND(B5))>TIMEVALUE("6:30 PM"), D5=1), (TIME(HOUR(C5), MINUTE(C5), SECOND(C5))-TIMEVALUE("9:30 AM")), (TIME(HOUR(C5), MINUTE(C5), SECOND(C5))-TIMEVALUE("9:30 AM")+TIMEVALUE("9:00 AM")))
```